# check if a number is - , + or x

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a number has a `-`, `+`, `x` or nothing in front of it?

Options to check would be:

```
20
+20
-20
x20
```

20 being any number.

Comment: Is this homework? `string.indexOf()`

Comment: Have you *tried* anything yourself?

Comment: Are you talking about strings, or numbers? "-20" has a "-" in front of it, but -20 is a negative number and can't really be said to have something in front of it. is "x" in this case the letter or do you mean to represent an arbitrary value?

Comment: if a *number* had any characters in front of it, it would no longer be a number.

Comment: Not homework and yes I tried myself. Have I come to the wrong website to ask for help?

Comment: @vol7ron "Depends". There are numbers, and then there are textual representation of numbers -- but in this case I suspect the question is *really* about strings...

Comment: Why do people feel the need to by rude. If you can't or dont wish to contibute then please take your negativity somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be a little more flexible and allow whitespace so you were looking for the first non-whitespace character that comes before a digit, you could use a regular expression:

```
var str = " + 20";

var match = str.match(/^\s*([^\d])/);
if (match) {
    switch(match[1]) {
        case "+":
            // put code here to handle this operator
            break;
        case "-":
            // put code here to handle this operator
            break;
        case "x":
            // put code here to handle this operator
            break;
        default:
            // put code here to handle unknown operator
            break;
    }
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fJcQJ/

Or, if you wanted a function that would return prefix and number, you could do this:

```
function parseNum(str) {
    var match = str.match(/^\s*([\+\-x]?)\s*(\d+)/);
    if (match) {
        return({
            num: parseInt(match[2], 10),
            prefix: match[1] ? match[1] : ""
        });
    }
    // nothing found of the right format
    return(null);
}
```

And, a working example with test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DCxcb/

Comment: Added function to my answer that will return both prefix and number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `string.charAt()` function to look at the first character of a string.

For example:

```
var myString = "...";
if(myString.charAt(0) == '+') //do something
else if(myString.charAt(0) == 'x') //do something else
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Example using regex to capture the first part and return an object.  Note: it's been amended to accept multiple prefixes (eg. *`-x20`*) and floating point numbers

```
function hasSign(str){
   return { value  : /^([-+x])*(\d+\.*\d*)$/.test(str.toString())
          , sign   : RegExp.$1
          , number : RegExp.$2
          };
}

   hasSign(-20);    // { value:true  , sign:"-"      , number="20"   }
   hasSign(+20);    // { value:true  , sign:""       , number="20"   }
   hasSign('20');   // { value:true  , sign:""       , number="20"   }
   hasSign('20.3'); // { value:true  , sign:""       , number="20.3" }  <-- float
   hasSign('-20');  // { value:true  , sign:"-"      , number="20"   }
   hasSign('+20');  // { value:true  , sign:"+"      , number="20"   }
   hasSign('x20');  // { value:true  , sign:"x"      , number="20"   }
   hasSign('a20');  // { value:false , sign:"Object" , number=""     }  <-- false
   hasSign('x');    // { value:false , sign:"Object" , number=""     }  <-- false
```

Comment: Thanks for this @vol7ton. What would I add to have it return the number aswell as the value and sign?

Comment: also.. I would need `hasSign('20'); // { value:true , sign:"" }
` to return true.. can that be done easily? I dont know RegExp.. Going to do a little reading on it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this is not homework! Here is such a function that for a number returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on whether the number is negative, zero, or positive, with credit to [A1ien51](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=142735):

```
function sgn(x)
{
  if(x>0)return 1;
  else if(x<0)return -1;
  else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Michael told,

For now I give you the sample.

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
var number="+a"; // your number will use for testing 
where_is_add=number.indexOf('+');
where_is_sub=number.indexOf('-');
where_is_mul=number.indexOf('*');
if(where_is_add==0){
    alert('There is +  in front of it.');
}
else if(where_is_sub==0){
    alert('There is -  in front of it.');
}
else if(where_is_mul==0){
    alert('There is *  in front of it.');
}
else {
    alert('Nothing  in front of it.');
}
</SCRIPT>
```